# How R subtracts a matrix from an integer

Tags: r, matrix

This a question about R's internals.  I am curious if someone could explain how the following call works.

```
# Let's just work with part of the iris data
data(iris)
df <- iris[1:10, 1:4]

# Now the question
1 - df
```

Does R create another matrix of equivalent dimensions?  Does it loop over all elements?  How is R subtracting a matrix from an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your example is a data.frame and not a matrix. I will refer to the data.frame case.

An S3 method is dispatched by the `Ops` group generic (see `methods("Ops")`). The relevant method is `Ops.data.frame`. Here are some excerpts with comments added by me:

```
#create an unevaluated function call
FUN <- get(.Generic, envir = parent.frame(), mode = "function")
f <- if (unary) 
    quote(FUN(left))
else quote(FUN(left, right))

#...
#a lot of checking and preparations
#...

#loop over the columns, create the function input and evaluate the function call
   for (j in seq_along(cn)) {
        left <- if (!lscalar) 
            e1[[j]]
        else e1
        right <- if (!rscalar) 
            e2[[j]]
        else e2
        value[[j]] <- eval(f)
    }
```

In case of the arguments to `-` being an integer vector and an integer matrix, both are treated as an integer vector, but `.Primitive("-")` preserves attributes, which includes the `dim` atribute of the matrix. See also `help("-")`.

Comment: Thank you, oversight on the data.frame.  Is there a significant difference between the function for a data.frame and a matrix or is the code essentially the same?  I didn't find an `Ops.matrix` method.

Comment: Read the last part of my answer. There is no S3 method for that case. It's handled by a `.Primitive` function.