# R subtracting matrix from numeric gives various results depending on the number of matrix rows

Tags: r, matrix

I am curious as to why R will (apparently) subtract a numeric from a matrix differently depending on the number or rows in that matrix.  Notice the various results below:

```
mat=matrix(rep(1,10),ncol=2)
sub=c(1,100)

test1 = sub - mat

## now increase the number of rows in the matrix, mat.

mat=matrix(rep(1,12),ncol=2)
test2 = sub - mat
```

Why are the *structures* of test1 and test2 different?  For reference I am using R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing."
Additionally, I found a somewhat similar question here: [How R subtracts a matrix from an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781311/how-r-subtracts-a-matrix-from-an-integer) but this refers to a data.frame and not a matrix so I thought it still worth asking.

Comment: It seems to me that you are expecting a row-wise operation, but R is performing a column-wise one (try `mat<-matrix(1:10,ncol=2); sub-mat` and see the result). That explains why you get a different result if you increase the number of rows

Comment: `sub` is treated as a column vector (as are all vanilla vectors) and "recycled" through the matrix column by column. You should have a look through the introductory R material, prolly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the results I get from running your code:

```
test1      
---     [,1] [,2]  
[1,]    0   99  
[2,]   99   0   
[3,]    0   99  
[4,]   99   0   
[5,]    0   99  

> test2      
---     [,1] [,2]  
[1,]    0    0  
[2,]   99   99  
[3,]    0    0  
[4,]   99   99  
[5,]    0    0  
[6,]   99   99
```

As far as I can tell, the operation does not act differently. The result looks different because in test 1 there are an odd number of rows and in the second test there are an even number of rows. The "sub" that you are subtracting from iterates through the matrix, starting with mat[1:2,1], then iterating down the rows. When it reaches the last row it wraps around to the second column. Since in test 1 there are an odd number of columns this the calculation looks like this:
`c(sub[1]-mat[5,1], sub[2]-mat[1,2])`

In essence, the matrix is being flattened into a vector before the operation occurs, and then is transformed back into a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Danny.  This is something that I will be telling my coworkers to avoid potentially catastrophic results in their code.  Also, may I ask that you edit your test1[,2] results from 9 to 99?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As per some of the comments about recycling, the issue you're facing is akin to the distinction between the results of `rep(sub, times=2)` and `rep(sub, each=2)`: recycling proceeds by repeating the vector as a whole as many times as necessary (or gives a warning if only part of the vector needs to be recycled).

Thus, you would get a more similar pattern (i.e., what you may have been expecting) by doing:

```
rep(sub, each=prod(dim(mat))/length(sub)) - mat
```

The value passed to the `each=` argument might look busy, but all I'm doing here is pre-recycling, and doing it in a way that gives the type of result that appears "similar" to us.

Perhaps an approach that would be more intuitive to you would be to note that your expected output from a row-wise application of the subtraction; we can apply the subtraction 1 row at a time (which does not require recycling for a single row, given that `ncol(mat) == length(sub)`) using:

```
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x)sub-x))
```